# VBA code causing inexplicable characters in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a personal project which uses excel to organize a lot of musical information.

In music, notes can be represented with numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and each of these numbers can have a sharp or flat symbol preceding it (notated with a "#" or "b")

I have several sheets that contain hundreds of cells of varying lengths, each cell containing a set of these numbers in various orders, for example: "1, #4, b7, 3" or "2, 5, 6, #2, #4"

Sometimes within a cell, a number will be underlined.  This is what is seeming to cause problems down the line.

I would like to assign a specific color to each number, and I've come up with some VBA code to accomplish this. I'm a musician, not a coder, but from reading this forum I've come up with the following code.  I'll just include an excerpt of it, the full code just keeps repeating this but with different values to account for all the possible notes.  Each note is listed twice, once with a comma after it, and once by itself - this is to account for the fact that I want the comma after a note to match its color, but the final note in a cell does not have a comma after it. There may be a better way of accomplishing this.

For the sake of troubleshooting this, I've put the problematic cells within column C.

```
Public Sub ColorCoding()
Set myRange = Range("C1:C100")  'The Range that contains the substring you want to change color

substr = "3,"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(106, 106, 106) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString

substr = "3"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(106, 106, 106) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString


substr = "4,"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString

substr = "4"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString
    
substr = "#4,"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(31, 88, 255) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString

substr = "#4"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(31, 88, 255) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString


substr = "5,"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString

substr = "5"   'This is the number to be colored:

For Each myString In myRange
    lenstr = Len(myString)
    lensubstr = Len(substr)
    For i = 1 To lenstr
        tempString = Mid(myString, i, lensubstr)
        If tempString = substr Then
            myString.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=lensubstr).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'this is the color for this number
        End If
    Next i
Next myString

End Sub
```

This code works as intended, except in some cells where one note is underlined, but others aren't.  Some cells with this criteria still work okay, but others get messed up to include incorrect/extra characters. Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image: B7 is an underlined cell, B8 is not underlined. B9 is an underlined cell]

Now here's where it gets weirder - when I click on the newly formatted incorrect cells, they both appear to have the regular correct values!
[image]

When I click into the cells to edit them, here's what I get:

[image]

If I save and close this document, I get an error when I open it back up:
[image]

I've tried opening this log file, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.

I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this or how to stop it from happening.  It happens consistently in the same places, but seemingly without much consistency in regards to the formatting of the cells.  Certain cells trigger this error based on where the underline occurs and whether the cell is underlined with a non-underlined portion, or non-underlined with an underlined portion.

Any help figuring out where the problem is happening would be appreciated, or if there's alternate code I might be able to try that doesn't cause this error, that would be greatly appreciated too!

Comment: In your text, at least, you are mixing oil and water. 1, 2 are single characters that evaluate to numbers. #4 are two characters that evaluate to a string. Any character can be displayed in the font of your choice. To change a character from without to with underscore you change the font, meaning a character with or without underscore is always the same character, just written in another font.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I fully understand your response - I don't want the VBA to change any of the underscoring, I'd like that to remain the same and only change the color of the character/string.  As for mixing strings/characters, why does that matter? The code seems to work fine except in cases where part of the cell is underscored.

Comment: I'm looking into your code but it will take a little while.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I came up with, admittedly, without finding the reason why yours misunderstood the instructions at times.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColorCoding()
    ' 231
    
    Dim Cols        As Variant
    Dim R           As Long         ' loop counter: rows

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")       ' change name to suit
        ' all used cells from A2 to the end of column A
        Cols = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)).Value
        For R = 1 To UBound(Cols)
            ' read the colours from the cells in the range
            Cols(R, 2) = .Cells(R + 1, "B").Interior.Color
        Next R
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' works faster this way
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")       ' change name to suit
        ' all used cells from C2 to the end of column C
        For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            SetNoteColors .Cells(R, "C"), Cols
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub SetNoteColors(Cell As Range, _
                          Cols As Variant)
    ' 231

    Dim CellVal     As String
    Dim Pstart      As Integer          ' start of substring
    Dim Pend        As Integer          ' end of substring
    Dim Sp()        As String           ' array of numbers in Cell.Value
    Dim i           As Integer          ' loop counter: Sp() index
    
    CellVal = Cell.Value
    If Len(CellVal) Then                ' skip if blank
        Sp = Split(CellVal, ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
            Do While Val(Sp(i)) = 0
                Sp(i) = Mid(Sp(i), 2)
            Loop
            Sp(i) = Val(Sp(i))
        Next i
        
        Pstart = 1
        i = 0
        Do
            Pend = InStr(Pstart, CellVal, ",") + 1
            If Pend = 1 Then Pend = Len(CellVal) + 1
            Cell.Characters(Pstart, Pend - Pstart).Font.Color = Cols(Sp(i), 2)
            Pstart = Pend
            i = i + 1
        Loop While Pend < Len(CellVal)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code loops through all used cells in column C of Sheet1 (rename to suit) and applies colour to the values found there. It will include any leading or trailing characters in the colouring, including a comma, if there is one.

Colours will depend upon the number, disregarding leading characters or underscores. 4, b4, #4, and any of these with underscore, will have the same colour. This will be comparatively easy to change within the system I have established.

Said system is contained in Sheet2 (rename to suit, and possibly hide from user's view or, to the contrary, move the table to Sheet1 and format it as a legend). Here is a picture.

[image]

The number is in column A and the colour in column B, starting from row 2. This much is hard programmed but whether you have 7, 8 or 16 colours can be adjusted in the list without change to the code. The code reads the colour from the cells in column B. Change the cell colour to change the colour to be given to the corresponding number in Sheet1!C:C. As I said, if you need different colours for 4, #4 and b4 the use of this list can be expanded. Underscores can also be made to make a difference with not too much effort.

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting so much time into this!

I set up the system, but when I try running it, I get: 

Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Any idea why?

Comment: One more thing - for my example I changed the range just be in column C, but in my actual sheets the information goes across many columns. The range would be something like C9:BK70 for example. How could I reflect that in the code?

Comment: Look for the sheet names `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` in the code. If either of these sheets don't exist by the encoded name you will get that kind of error. As a rule of thumb, always tell on which line an error occurs (click on *Debug* in the error message). To cure the error I assume change the sheet names in the code to be exactly as they are in your workbook.

Comment: I do have Sheet1 and Sheet2 in my workbook, Sheet1 is the sheet with the data that needs to be changed and Sheet2 contains the coloring system

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error, then? Don't conflate *Name* and *CodeName*. The name mentioned here is the name you find on the tab. Are your columns C:BK all of the same length? If not, on which column can I determine the maximum  length? Perhaps in column A?

Comment: Yep, both Sheets are named that on their tabs.  Yes, all the columns are the same length.

I believe the error is happening in line 11

Comment: That would be line `For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`, right? Check the name of "Sheet1". Look for a leading or trailing blank in the name on the tab.

Comment: It's the line after that: `Cols = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)).Value`. No leading or trailing spaces on the sheet names

Comment: That's interesting. Which version of Excel do you use? Add a leading period before "Range" in `Cols = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), ...` to become `Cols = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), ...` I've added this period in  my answer as well.

Comment: This is so bizzare.  I'm in Excel 2016 and the leading period allowed the code to run, but I'm getting the same strange error as in my original code. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Mswkyz8.png)

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error - once. On second run the code corrected its earlier result and didn't repeat the fault. But when I wanted to close the workbook it claimed "extensive damage", tried to create a skeleton copy and failed in even that. I conclude that Excel isn't made for this. You might try Word. But if you do wish to stick with Excel and your present system of colouring and underscoring, you might consider placing each note in its own narrow cell, perhaps hide gridlines and draw borders where you want them.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for all your help and the suggestions. It's greatly appreciated!